# Jquery treeview nodes will not toggle after an ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two dialog boxes within my view.  Each of these dialog boxes have ajax commands within them for instance the first one does a `POST` and second one does a `LOAD`.

The issue is after I select from a checkbox list in dialog box 1 and hit UpdatePage button, my model gets updated just fine.  However, The second dialog box containing the tree view with another checbobox list/nodes will not toggle at all. It does retain its previous state though: The checkboxes selected previosuly are checked but it will not toggle at all.

The following function creates the dialog box 1 and upon successful completion of the post command in this dialog box that the second dialog box and the treeview within, will not toggle.

```
function initDailog() {

        RunDialog = $("#runDatestreeview").dialog({ closeOnEscape: true, stack: false, autoOpen: true,
            modal: false, resizable: true, draggable: true, title: 'Select Run Dates to Auto-Populate Form Fields & Test Exceptions:',
            width: 600, height: 500, position: 'center',
            open: function (type, data) {
            },
            buttons: { UpdatePage: function () {
                //storing the value of treeview selections in dialog box 2
                var originalContent = $("#treeview").html();
                $.post(runDatesUrl,
              $("#form").serialize(),
               function (data) {
                   $("#runDatestreeview").remove();
                   //removing the div which contains the treeview
                   $("#treeview").remove();
                   $("#testExceptiontreeview").remove();
                   $("#main").html(data);
                  //setting back the value of the div which contains the treeview 
                   $("#treeview").html(originalContent);
               }, "html");
            },
                Cancel: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                      }
            }
        });

        RunDialog.closest("div.ui-dialog").appendTo("#form");
    }
```

Treeview defined in dialog box 2, in its seperate JS file:

```
$("#errorCodes ul").treeview({
collapsed: true,
prerendered: false
});
```

The HTML for The div which contains the tree view:

```
<div id="treeview" title="Dialog Title" style="font-size: 10px; font-weight: normal;
    overflow: scroll; width: 800px; height: 450px; display: none;">
    <div id="errorCodes">
        @Html.RenderTree(CacheHelper.ErrorCodes(), ec => ec.Name, ec => ec.Children.ToList(), ec => (ec.ID).ToString(), null, "e")
    </div>
    <div id="inputReps" style="display: none;">
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: If I understand right it is the treeview `$("#errorCodes ul")` which stops working? If so, is `$("#errorCodes ul")` element part of the `originalContent` or within any of the HTML elements  you remove with one of the `.remove()` calls?  If that is the case you might need to re-bind the treeview again. When you remove an element from the DOM all it's events are removed too. Even if you re-add it it is not the same but now a new element, therefore you would have to re-bind the treeview. You might be able to solve this with `.clone` but that depends on what your response details.

Comment: In general it would help a lot if you would be able to post the rendered HTML which contains all the elements you are referencing in your script, such as `#errorCodes ul`, `#treeview`, etc.

Comment: My apologies for not posting the relevant HTML for the tree view. You are right errorCodes ul stops working which resides in the div tree view. So If I understand it correctly, If I re-bind the tree view again, how can I set the state to the previous state. With my current code, its previous state is there but like you said probably the events are not their any more. I am posting the DOM shortly

Comment: Should probably tag this ASP.NET MVC + Razor or something. Can't exactly run it in Firefox. Also please fix your line break at the end.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET MVC are you running, anyway?

Comment: @davidkennedy85 I am running MVC 3 with jquery-1.8.3 and this app is only intended for IE.

Comment: @tamtam: The collapse/expand state should be remembered regardless (mind you I tested this only in Chrome not IE) and the events will be working again ones you re-bind the plug-in. Just make sure when re-binding the plug-in you leave out any default states such as `collapsed: true,` etc. I added a working DEMO to my answer. Just note the exception. If you have an item with a default state applied through a class, such as `folder 3` in the DEMO, it will re-apply that. Otherwise it should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a play-around with this and if you store the `.html()` and then after adding it again, re-bind the plugin again, the state is **kind-off** remembered.

I used the code from the fiddle I created for your last question and slightly updated it.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/LVUGk/) - Store HTML, remove Tree, Add new Tree, set HTML and rebind treeView

---

In the above DEMO I'm binding the treeview on load, collapse/expand the tree view and then hit the `store/remove/attach` button. After that the tree looks as before and collapse/expand/toggle still work.

The `store/remove/attach` button will do the following when clicked:

- store the HTML of the `ul` element which is the treeview
- remove the `ul` element
- re-add a new `ul` element
- adds the original HTML to the new `ul`
- re-bind the `ul` to the treeview plugin

It remembers the state, if the tree was collapsed, it renders collapsed and expanded it renders expanded.

Except for the default closed element (File 3) as the `close` class will be re-applied the first time it renders.

Other than that it looks OK.

---

#### Code from DEMO

---

*HTML*

```
<div id="treeviewcontrol"> <a href="#"> collapse </a><a href="#"> expand </a><a href="#"> toggle </a>

</div>
<ul id="tree" class="filetree">
  <li><span class="folder">Folder 1</span>

    <ul>
      <li><span class="file">Item 1.1</span>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="folder">Folder 2</span>

    <ul>
      <li><span class="folder">Subfolder 2.1</span>

        <ul id="folder21">
          <li><span class="file">File 2.1.1</span>

          </li>
          <li><span class="file">File 2.1.2</span>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><span class="file">File 2.2</span>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="closed"><span class="folder">Folder 3 (closed at start)</span>

    <ul>
      <li><span class="file">File 3.1</span>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span class="file">File 4</span>

  </li>
</ul>
<button id="cloneTree" type="button">Store/Remove/Attach Tree</button>
```

*Script*

```
$("#tree").treeview({
  control: "#treeviewcontrol",
  prerendered: false
});

$("#cloneTree").click(function () {
  var $tree = $("#tree");
  var originalHtml = $tree.html();

  $tree.remove();

  var newBrowser = $('<ul id="tree" class="filetree"></ul>')

  newBrowser.html(originalHtml);
  $("body").append(newBrowser);

  $("#tree").treeview({
    control: "#treeviewcontrol",
    prerendered: false
  });
});
```

*CSS*

```
.treeview, .treeview ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
.treeview ul {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 4px;
}
.treeview .hitarea {
  background: url(images/treeview-default.gif) -64px -25px no-repeat;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  margin-left: -16px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/* fix for IE6 */
 * html .hitarea {
  display: inline;
  float:none;
}
.treeview li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 0pt 3px 16px;
}
.treeview a.selected {
  background-color: #eee;
}
#treecontrol {
  margin: 1em 0;
  display: none;
}
.treeview .hover {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.treeview li {
  background: url(images/treeview-default-line.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.treeview li.collapsable, .treeview li.expandable {
  background-position: 0 -176px;
}
.treeview .expandable-hitarea {
  background-position: -80px -3px;
}
.treeview li.last {
  background-position: 0 -1766px
}
.treeview li.lastCollapsable, .treeview li.lastExpandable {
  background-image: url(images/treeview-default.gif);
}
.treeview li.lastCollapsable {
  background-position: 0 -111px
}
.treeview li.lastExpandable {
  background-position: -32px -67px
}
.treeview div.lastCollapsable-hitarea, .treeview div.lastExpandable-hitarea {
  background-position: 0;
}
.treeview-red li {
  background-image: url(images/treeview-red-line.gif);
}
.treeview-red .hitarea, .treeview-red li.lastCollapsable, .treeview-red li.lastExpandable {
  background-image: url(images/treeview-red.gif);
}
.treeview-black li {
  background-image: url(images/treeview-black-line.gif);
}
.treeview-black .hitarea, .treeview-black li.lastCollapsable, .treeview-black li.lastExpandable {
  background-image: url(images/treeview-black.gif);
}
.treeview-gray li {
  background-image: url(images/treeview-gray-line.gif);
}
.treeview-gray .hitarea, .treeview-gray li.lastCollapsable, .treeview-gray li.lastExpandable {
  background-image: url(images/treeview-gray.gif);
}
.treeview-famfamfam li {
  background-image: url(images/treeview-famfamfam-line.gif);
}
.treeview-famfamfam .hitarea, .treeview-famfamfam li.lastCollapsable, .treeview-famfamfam li.lastExpandable {
  background-image: url(images/treeview-famfamfam.gif);
}
.treeview .placeholder {
  background: url(images/ajax-loader.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  display: block;
}
.filetree li {
  padding: 3px 0 2px 16px;
}
.filetree span.folder, .filetree span.file {
  padding: 1px 0 1px 16px;
  display: block;
}
.filetree span.folder {
  background: url(images/folder.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.filetree li.expandable span.folder {
  background: url(images/folder-closed.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
.filetree span.file {
  background: url(images/file.gif) 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Appriciate your help!  your the best!